# How to set a default queryset for DateFromToRangeFilter in django-filter?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a filter on which I've set a date range filter.

```
class UtenteActivityFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
   date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
   class Meta:
       model = Activity
       fields = ['date']
```

I am using this filter to populate a table.

```
class UtenteDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Utente
    template_name = 'users/utente_detail.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        f = UtenteActivityFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Activity.objects.filter(author=self.object))
        context['filter'] = f
        return context
```

Now my table is populated by all the data from the queryset when I load the page without any date set in the filter.

How do I set the initial state of the filter to a defined value (or queryset)?

I wish my table to show just activities from "today" when the page is ofirst opened, but to still be able to filter among all the models.

I already defined a qs of activities for "today":

```
# context['today_activities'] = Activity.objects.filter(created__gte=timezone.now().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0))
```

but setting it as a queryset restrict the filtering to that only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, it's by redefining the `qs` property.

```
@property
def qs(self):
    parent = super().qs
    if not self.is_valid():
        # add default daterange for today
        start_date = timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
        end_date = timezone.now().replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)
        field_name = "date"
        lookup_gte = "%s__gte" % (field_name)
        lookup_lte = "%s__lte" % (field_name)
        kwargs = {lookup_gte: start_date, lookup_lte: end_date}
        return parent.filter(**kwargs)
    else:
        return parent
```